# error with 'str' object has no attribute 'save' for my django project

Tags: python, django

I take an error as 'str' object has no attribute 'save'. I couldn't find where is the problem.
How can I fix it? [enter image description here][1]
error screenshot:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87joO.png
my model code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import yazi
from .forms import CreateForm
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your views here.
def postliste_view(request):
    yazilar = yazi.objects.all()

    return render(request, "liste.html", {"yazilar": yazilar})

def postdetail_view(request, id):
    yaziNesne = yazi.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "detail.html",  {"yazi" : yaziNesne})


def postcreate_view(request):
    form = CreateForm()

    return render(request, "create.html", {"form" : form} )

def formdoldur_view(request):
    form = CreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
       yaziNesne = form.save(commit=False)
       yaziNesne = slug = slugify(yaziNesne.başlık)
       yaziNesne.save()

    return render(request, "gonderildi.html", {})





def postupdate_view(request, id):
    if request.GET:
        baslik = request.GET.get("baslik")
        metin = request.GET.get("metin")

        yaziNesne = yazi.objects.get(id=id)
        yaziNesne.başlık = baslik
        yaziNesne.metin = metin
        yaziNesne.save()
    else:
         yaziNesne = yazi.objects.get(id=id)
         
    return render(request, "update.html", {"yazi" : yaziNesne})



def postdelete_view(request, id):
    yaziNesne = yazi.objects.get(id=id)
    yaziNesne.delete()
    
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/post")

# database api --> veritabanı işlemlerini yapan fonksiyonlar


#
```

django shell --> djangonun python kabuğu

Comment: `yaziNesne.slug = slugify(yaziNesne.başlık)`, not `yaziNesne = slug = slugify(yaziNesne.başlık)`.

Comment: For your `postupdate_view`: a GET request should *not* update a record: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html